# How to download files over 6MB

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I have the most basic problem ever. The user wants to export some data which is around 20-70k records and can take from 20-40 seconds to execute and the file can be around 5-15MB.

Currently my code is as such:

```
User clicks a button which makes an API call to a Java Lambda 
AWS Lambda Handler calls a method to get the data from DB and generate excel file using Apache POI
Set Response Headers and send the file as XLSX in the response body
```

I am now faced with two bottlenecks:

- API Gateway times out after 29 seconds; if file takes longer to
  generate it will not work and user get 504 in the browser
- Response from lambda can only be 6MB, if file is bigger the user will
  get 413/502 in the browser

What should be my approach to just download **A GENERATED RUNTIME file (not pre-built in s3)** using AWS?

Comment: Can you choose settings to get the data in 3 or 4 chunks then combine to one file later?

Comment: @SolarMike what do you mean? The user clicks on the export button and just wants to get an xlsx file with all the data from the past month (which is stored in the DB)

Comment: So why does the export button not just give the whole database like 70k records?

Comment: @SolarMike the whole database has millions of records. The export is from the last month which is around 70k records that the user wants to see in the excel. The problem is the lambda limitations... Works fine for like 5k records

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep it simple (no additional queues or async processing) this is what I'd recommend to overcome the two limitations you describe:

1. Use the new AWS Lambda Endpoints. Since that option doesn't use the AWS API Gateway, you shouldn't be restricted to the 29-sec timeout (not 100% sure about this).
2. Write the file to S3, then get a temporary presigned URL to the file and return a redirect (HTTP 302) to the client. This way you won't be restricted to the 6MB response size.

Comment: I can't find the `AWS Lambda Endpoints`. I'm using normal spring boot APIs working as lambdas and they all have AWS API Gateway

Comment: @daph111 take a look at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints-for-single-function-microservices/. It's a recent feature (Apr 2022). Enabling lambda function URLs is just a "checkbox" in the portal UI. If you use a  tool you use to deploy your lambdas, you should look if it's already supported (for example, with serverless framework you just need to set url:true, see https://www.serverless.com/blog/aws-lambda-function-urls-with-serverless-framework).

Answer (score 0):

When your script takes more than 30s to run on your server then you implement queues, you can get help from this tutorial on how to implement queues using SQS or any other service.

https://mikecroft.io/2018/04/09/use-aws-lambda-to-send-to-sqs.html

Once you implement queues your timeout issue will be solved because now you are fetching your big data records in the background thread on your server.

Once the excel file is ready in the background then you have to save it in your s3 bucket or hard disk on your server and create a downloadable link for your user.

Once the download link is created you will send that to your user via email. In this case, you should have your user email.

So the summary is Apply queue -> send a mail with the downloadable file.

Comment: let me edit this for you in much simpler words.

Comment: Which framework on language you are using ?

Comment: Spring Boot + Java

Comment: Check the answer now. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possible options for you.

1. Use Javascript skills to rescue. Accept the request from browser/client and immediately respond from server that your file preparation is in progress. Meanwhile continue preparing the file in the background (sperate job). Using java script, keep polling the status of file using separate request. Once the file is ready return it back.
2. Smarter front-end clients use web-sockets to solve such problems.
3. In case DB query is the culprit, cache the data on server side, if possible, for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of some sophisticated solution (though that would be interesting).

1. Inventory. You will split the Excel in portions of say 10 k rows. Calculate the number of docs.
2. For every Excel generation called you have a reduced work load.

Whether e-mail, page with links, using a queue you decide.

The advantage is staying below e-mail limits, response time-outs, denial of service.

(In Excel one could also create a master document, but I have no experience.)